# How to create in Java a validator to check that an integer is among a list of specific supplied values

Tags: java, spring

I need to use javax.valitation to create a validator for an integer field.
That integer field has to be a value among a provided list of values (i.e. 5, 10 or 15) to pass the validation.

In particular, my field is:

```
@IntegerValueAmong({5, 10, 15})
private Integer myNumber;
```

The IntegerValueAmong annotation is defined as:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = IntegerValueAmongValidator.class)
public @interface IntegerValueAmong {
  String message() default "Value must an integer value among";
  Class<?>[] groups() default {};
  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
  int[] value() default {};
}
```

And the IntegerValueAmongValidator I have tried to do is:

```
public class IntegerValueAmongValidator implements ConstraintValidator<IntegerValueAmong, Integer> {
  @Override
  public boolean isValid(Integer integer, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
      return integer == 5 || integer == 10 || integer == 15;
  }
}
```

But I don't want to have 5, 10 and 15 as hardcoded values and I would like to access to the array passed to the IntegerValueAmong annotation put on the field.

Comment: Well, what did you try?   This isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: Please don't use salutations or thanks in questions.

Comment: @aled I have just removed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you ask the question shows that you have shown little effort in reading the documentation. If you would you would have noticed the [`initialize`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.html#initialize-A-) method. This method is invoked **before** the call to `isValid` and receives the current annotation. With this you thus can configure the validator for that specific annotation.

```java
public class IntegerValueAmongValidator implements ConstraintValidator<IntegerValueAmong, Integer> {

  private List<Integer> allowedValues = Collections.emptyList();

  @Overide
  public void initialize(IntegerValueAmong annot) {
    allowedValues =  IntStream.of(annot.value()).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(Integer integer, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
    return integer != null && allowedValues.contains(integer);
  }
}
```